# verify the function is lipschitz or not

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Question

$a>0$ ,$b>0$, $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$,$t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ . The set D is defined as $D=\{(t,x)\in \mathbb{R^2}:|t-t_0|\leq a , |x-x_0|\leq b \}$ .
$a(t,x)$ is a continuous function on $D$ .
verify whether the function $f(t,x)=(1+a(t,x))x^2$ is lipschitz or not with respect to $x$ on $D$.

My approach: I tried to take values of $a$ and $b$ and tried to find an example for not Lipschitz. But I am unable to make it in general.

Please help in finding a general example.

Comment: it is satisfying lipschitz condition . $|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)|\leq (1+\sqrt{a})|x_1-x_2|$

Comment: If it is Lipschitz  it would be differentiable almost everywhere w.r.t. $x$. Any continuous $a(t,x)$ which is not almost everywhere differentiable w,r.t. $x$ would be a counter-example.

Comment: What is the point of isolating a "$1+$" in the continuous factor of $x^2$?